# method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 error in a small app

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, proguard, dalvik

We do have a small app, though, using around 10jars. I am stuck with it.
I configured Proguard and it still says the same thing. We only have 500+ unused methods as per the Proguard results. What could I be doing wrong or missing?

Below are the gradle file dependencies:

Our "library" module:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-1.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-urlconnection-1.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.48.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.48.jar')
    compile files('libs/otto-1.3.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.5.1.jar')
    compile project(':googlemapssdkm4b_lib')
}
```

The app module:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':sherpaTaxiLibrary')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':v4PrefFragment')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.1'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
}
```

Below is my proguard code:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt 
-printseeds seeds.txt 
-printusage unused.txt 
-printmapping mapping.txt 
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-allowaccessmodification
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-repackageclasses ''

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------

##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

-dontwarn rx.**, org.w3c.dom.**, com.squareup.okhttp.**, org.codehaus.mojo.**, 
java.nio.file.**, retrofit.** 

-libraryjars libs
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.* { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.* { *; }
-keep class retrofit.* { *; }
-keep class com.example.testobfuscation.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }


-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 

# Guava exclusions (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava)
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
} 

# Guava depends on the annotation and inject packages for its annotations, keep them both
-keep public class javax.annotation.**
-keep public class javax.inject.**
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `We only have 500+ unused methods` ... **only**! Try grouping your methods, in order to have less. And please remove all unused ones.

Comment: Hello Frank, the 500+ unused methods where from the libs that we have included in our project. Ours was very small with only around 100 very short classes.

Comment: You has to many libs. Are you sure you should use them all ?

Comment: Yeah, we use them all. we do have the ormlite for the db. jackson for the json. okhttp, okio, picasso and retrofit for the network. google play services for location, email login, place, etc. google maps for business for the map. butterknife for injecting views and braintree for payments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to fix it. The proguard code was actually fine, but I placed it in the wrong file. It should be in the module which generates the dex file. I have placed it in the static library before.

Also, I used https://gist.github.com/dmarcato/d7c91b94214acd936e42 to strip out the Google Play Services packages that I do not use. 
I placed the code in the gradle file of the module which generates the APK.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard can probably remove many classes and methods for you, but your configuration is fairly conservative, explicitly keeping many classes, fields, and methods:

```
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.* { *; }
.....
```

You may have even more options in a separate file, e.g. for the Facebook SDK?

Note that the file `proguard-project.txt` can essentially be empty to start with, since the bulk of the configuration is already specified in the shared configuration file `${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt` (referenced from `project.properties`). Creating a better configuration with the right `-keep` options may then require some research and experimentation.

You also shouldn't specify `-injars` or `-libraryjars` options in your configuration file. The Gradle build process already automatically specifies all the necessary `-injars`, `-outjars`, and `-libraryjars` for you.

Comment: I just realized that Proguard turned on, without additional configurations work in a project that does not have any module dependency.
I am trying to let it work in a module which is a dependency of the main project I am running. I tried to put Proguard on both and it is not removing the needed stuff.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @EricLafortune, the Proguard worked now, but was only able to strip 400+ methods from Google play Services. Is that expected? Thanks